# Translation in French of a medical expression

Tags: traduction, terminologie, science, santé-et-médecine

En médecine légale, comment traduit-on "pugilistic attitude" lorsqu'on examine les corps de personnes retrouvées dans des incendies? Je voudrais l'expression exacte, ma question s'adresse donc à quelqu'un qui a quelques connaissances en sciences médicales.

Comment: Peut-être que « cadavre » conviendrait mieux que corps ici (un corps n'est pas forcément mort). Pour ceux qui ne connaissent pas le terme anglais ["*pugilistic attitude*"](http://bit.ly/2hOHKKr) (p. 213) est employé en médecine légale pour décrire la position d'un corps calciné, bras en avant et genoux repliés parce que rétractés sous l'effet de la chaleur (comme un boxeur en position de défense→pugilistic). Je ne connais pas le terme de médecine légale en français mais dans les romans policiers et dans la presse on parle de corps calciné en « position fœtale ».

Comment: La position n'est pas forcément "fœtale". Pas forcément mort: en médecine légale, si. De plus c'est le terme utilisé.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *pugilistc stance* can simply be translated **attitude du boxeur**.

From [Wikimedecine France](http://www.wikimedecine.fr/Agents_physiques_de_d%C3%A9c%C3%A8s).

> Noter l'attitude du corps (carbonisation → normalement le corps est recroquevillé en une **attitude "du lutteur", "du boxeur"**).